# Why are my questions downvoted for no reason?

Tags: support, down-votes

Lots of my questions were downvoted or have no votes at all for bad or even no reasons,even though I try to do my best at researching and studying the topic(there are some good ones too). Can anyone please help me with this?
And also sometimes less important /valuable questions are hugely upvoted while some good questions are downvoted.

And I swear when my question even sometimes actually "good" ones have a downvote at like 3 views.

And also why is there someone always there saying that there's like 200,000 answers when none of them are even good?!?!

Another thing my content was also considered "spam" before and it may look like that because I'm trying to ask good questions,but when I  ask an actual good question some knowitall ruins it.

It's actually ironic that I'm saying
this but I don't care how many downvotes this gets. Downvote this if you like because what can I do anymore?

SE was actually kinda cool back then where we had more freedom.Now it's a literal hellhole and I'm not taking it back.

And one more thing to say,even if I edit and make the question better ,it gets even more downvotes,like what am I supposed to do?

One of my friends wanted to learn about stars in general ,and the first answer said they had the balls to say this "that they should research it more" like someone wants to actually hear an answer from a real person not just some auto-generated bot.No wonder why your reviews are so low Stack Overflow,maybe actually not do everything with your bootleg bots!!!!!!!

---

Well I think I'll just start to post "better" and more "interesting" questions,but I can't because I'm banned from asking questions even though my reputation score has gone up ,but again what can I do at this point?

It's just like the reviews said "trash and full of toxic people."

That's all I have to say. Sorry if this seems like a rant or something like that.

Just expression my opinion because I'm trying to ask questions and this happens way too much.

Comment: @orthocresol I only sometimes use a topic like that because If I try to use another topic than someone's gonna say its duplicated,but I try to answer questions that make sense in my head,but somehow people think its bad. But I don't even know what to do. And then I can't even ask any more questions and then I edit a questions and my rep goes up and it's the same cycle.

Comment: Like actually I'm not personally affected by downvoted but its just frustrating having people doing the same content -or worse getting upvotes.But what can I do?

Comment: As much as I would have wanted to downvote this. I'm refraining from doing so. I understand the frustration that happens when people downvote your questions and seeing "similar" questions get upvotes. Have you attempted to see what differentiates your posts and the ones that get upvoted?

Comment: @Bruh I haven't downvoted any of your questions but I do want to talk about your field. Most of your questions have the pattern "X is a compounds. Does it exist?" and you've linked the relevant wiki article which clearly says in the first line that it is a hypothetical compound. So, why is your question arising? And you do have valuable comments beneath your question. If you are not getting any answer, please compile the comments and make an answer yourself (if you feel you've got your answer). No one is stopping you. If you are getting frustrated, then change your field of questions.

Comment: Let's do some statistics. Of your 12 questions, only 2 out of 12 question have negative scores, 8 of them have answers, 2 of them have been closed. That's not bad considering that your account is only about one month old. One more thing, I haven't seen you replying to the comment you are receiving. Please feel free to clarify/give a reply back to our comments. If you are replying back, we'd think you are not interested in us. So, instead of ranting, I suggest you to reply back to our comments.

Comment: @NilayGhosh There are a number of deleted questions with negative scores. I agree with the second half of your comment, though.

Comment: @orthocresol Yes, that makes sense. To OP: (typo to above comment "if you are" -> "if you aren't"). One more thing. You are editing your post quite a lot and that is spamming the homepage. I do not know your intentions, but such trivial edits are frowned upon. If you want to make changes, gather all your small edits and do it in one edit. The last thing is you are trying to [self-vandalize your posts](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/150812/revisions). That's a no-no. That will outdate the answer and more important, the time and energy spent by the answerer will go to waste.

Comment: I'm the one who has pointed out the large number of hits on your Google search-type questions. And there are plenty of good to great answers, usually in the form of referred publications. My guess is that you are not digging into the literature before posting. My suggestion is that you familiarize yourself with Google Scholar, PubMed, ChemSpider, and other resources and go there first. If something remains unclear, post it here with supporting information and the relevant query.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal yes I actually have and still people downvote my questions at like the third view,and then I edit the question and I still get downvotes, I don't even know what to do at that point because now my reputation is going to go down for something that's out of my control now.

Comment: @BruhMoments "I don't even know what to do "Did you not read my 3 comments above?

Comment: @BruhMoments Don't think much about rep. It's just an way to stop people with wrong mindsets to vandalise the system. You have very much enough rep to do most of the things here in SE. You need to understand that your rep is not going down as fast as you are thinking. Every upvote gives you +10 rep whereas a downvote takes away only 2 rep. You need 5 downvotes to counter an upvote. The fact that you are one of the users with most rep gain this month proves that you are doing good enough for rep. The only thing you need to improve is the research you do before asking.

Comment: **Your efforts are the imaginary currency in which you pay for the services of this site**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disclaimer: I can't answer for everybody, it is a "feature" of Stack Exchange that upvotes and downvotes are personal.

On one hand I can empathise with you: it's good to have a natural curiosity about science. Thus, forgive me for being blunt, but I will point out the likely reasons for downvotes here:

1. *The questions are pretty repetitive.* A number of your questions centre around similar themes: "why is X so toxic", or some kind of periodic trend which goes like "F exists, Cl exists, Br exists, I exists, but At doesn't". People wouldn't mind one of these every now and then, but you've done quite a few of these in a short span ​of time, and it could come across as spammy.
2. *You could find answers for these online.* As has been suggested on several of your questions, especially the toxicity ones, a simple Google search or the Wikipedia article could address the question quite well. If there's some issue with the Wikipedia article, like you don't understand a part of it, then you can mention that in the question; it makes it a more well-developed question which has some of *yourself* injected into it, rather than one that sounds rather like a generic Google search query.
3. *The questions are just not so interesting.* This sounds harsh, so I will try to offer more explanation. The type of questions you are asking are often centred on one specific compound or hypothetical compound. At the end of the day, these types of questions don't generalise very well and end up just being factoids that don't really give any chemical insight. It's nice to find out one piece of trivia about $\ce{Mn2O7}$ for example, but it's not obvious how this gives you or us a deeper insight into chemistry as a science.

   Much of chemistry is about searching for *concepts* which can be applied to a wide range of compounds. That's what textbooks explain, and that's what you tend to be taught in chemistry courses. Chemistry *isn't* just about collecting a bunch of facts about a bunch of compounds, which is what your questions tend to aim at. That's the job of an encyclopedia, or Wikipedia. Most chemists aren't really interested in having 50 random unconnected facts about which compound exists and which doesn't: it's more interesting having 1 theory which can explain a range of physical properties and chemical behaviour.

Comment: Point 1 is the most important. I personally don't have any problems to the questions but considering that the posts are becoming repetitive and the fact that the post (as it stands) are self-explanatory, can be problematic. I mean to say that OP is asking whether a compound exist and linking the wiki article where it clearly says "it is a hypothetical compound", so the question makes no sense. If OP asks, "why is it hypothetical", then it can be a different story and worth answering.

Comment: Why even bother to downvote a question when it's already closed?!?!!? You're putting salt into the wound.

Comment: @BruhMoments There is no rule that once a question is closed, you can't downvote it. If it is getting closed, I suggest you to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @BruhMoments, a question leaves the front page with 4 downvotes, Don't take rep personally, it helps no-one.